# Universal USB Charger for Raspberry pi 2

Tags: usb, hardware

i have a charger with 5 V output and 1.5 A output

https://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/accessory/ac-60/specifications/#

i know raspberry pi 2 needs 5V 1A

it is ok to use the raspberry with this charger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is ok to use the raspberry with this charger?

Yes.

Comment: great, it can be more readable for the consumers to see "max" 1500 mA or "up to" 1500mA on the product documentation

Comment: If you attach something hefty to a USB port it may not cover that, but a wifi adapter, mouse, and keyboard should be okay

Comment: It may (or may not) work. Many "chargers" comply with the USB charger spec, which lets voltage drop to 3.6V. There is no indication which spec this is designed to. All USB chargers supply 5V on light load, so should work with a standalone Pi, but may cause problems with heavier loads.

Comment: I guess if they say *"Charger output voltage: 5.0V"* either it is true, or it isn't -- but that's the case with everything in print.  I've used various USB style chargers with pis and never had a problem with them.

Comment: i have used the charger and have no problems